# Create "x" number of new tabs. Then in main tab, sum all E13s from sheet1:sheetX

Tags: vba, excel

We need a macro that will create "X" number of tabs that will be titled "batch 1" to "batch "X"".  An integer is entered in cell "A15" that will say how many tabs will be made.  Then in a cell in the first tab we need to take the sum of all of the E13 cells created from the number inputted in "A15."  The code below creates "X" number of tabs but we're stuck on how to add the E13 values together.  `=SUM("Batch 1":"Batch X"!E13)` is my best guess but I am trying to figure out how to define a variable "X" to be equal to the integer in cell "A15."  Thanks in advance!

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("A15").Value
    Sheets("Resource Estimator").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Batch" & " " & i
Next i
```

Comment: does each created `tab` get a number on cell `E13` and what is that number? a random number?

Comment: Why not use the `i` and multiply it with the value in `Worksheets("Batch 1").` (which is copied anyway), try inputting to cell "A3" in with:  `Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = i * Worksheets("Batch 1").Range("E13").Value`

Comment: @ShaiRado Because I guess the E13 within the sheets Batch 1 to x will be different from Batch 1 after some time when data has changed/was filled into the Batch sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create the `SUM` formula with VBA within the loop.

```
Sub Create()
    Dim i As Integer, SumFormula As String
    For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("A15").Value
        Sheets("Resource Estimator").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Batch " & i

        If i = 1 Then
            SumFormula = "=SUM('" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!E13" 'begin sum formula
        Else
            SumFormula = SumFormula & ",'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!E13" 'iterate sum formula
        End If
    Next i

    SumFormula = SumFormula & ")" 'end sum formula
    Sheet1.Range("A16").Formula = SumFormula 'write sum formula to cell A16
End Sub
```

Here in the first iteration (`i = 1`) of the `for` loop the creation of the sum formula begins with `=SUM('Batch 1'!E13` for all other sheets the sum formula is extended by `,'Batch i'!E13` where `i` is the sheet number. And in the end the formula is ended with a bracket `)` and written into range `A16`.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks for the help.